# Is 1hr 50min enough for an International to Domestic connection at Melbourne Airport?

Tags: short-connections, mel

I am flying from the U.K. to Melbourne, Australia. I then have to catch a flight to Sydney (a separate booking) but I'm worried about how long I need in between landing and the Sydney flight. I land at 18:55 and my Sydney flight is 20:45. I only have hand luggage.

Is this enough time?

Comment: If the booking is separate then you are cutting it very tight.  Check in online for the second flight if at all possible, and pray that your first flight is early.

Comment: What airlines are involved?

Comment: EY460 is [often late into MEL](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/ETD460). You are not likely to make this connection.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not enough time. Essentially you are looking to connect from a twenty hour plus international flight to another flight within 1 hour 50 minutes, with immigration control factored in.

The twenty hour plus international flight can easily be delayed one hour or more. It is very very tight, basically almost too tight. I advise you check the international flight to see its historical percent on time performance. That will give you an idea of the probabilities you are playing with.

If there is the possibility to change the second flight or even the first, you are advised to do so. A 20:45 flight is **likely** to be the last flight for that route on the day meaning its very likely if you miss it, you will have to book a hotel and incur further costs before continuing on your journey the next day.

Comment: Change whichever is cheaper/less inconvenient. Typically that would be the domestic flight, however it's up to him/her.

Comment: Well, it's obviously not a nonstop; there's a change at AUH.